# C# Track schanges on the Excel ( ListObjectChangeHandler )

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am trying to develop a program for tracking changes in the Excel table object to handle it in the further.

For my PoV it must be truck some events in a specific area. If you have some useful example could you  please share it )

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are interested in the [Worksheet.Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Change) event which is fired when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link. This event does not occur when cells change during a recalculation. Use the [Calculate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)) event to trap a sheet recalculation. For example, the following code example sets the values in the range `A1:A10` to be uppercase as the data is entered into the cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Set the values to be uppercase
    Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```